# Should I update certified Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, updates, dell

I have the laptop [DELL Inspiron 5759](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201507-18601/) (the config is a little bit different from the one is specified). For some reason, it was freezing each time I was launching 'About this computer' - info. It has Ubuntu 14.04 LTS out of the box, so I decided to update it to solve the problem. When I opened Software and Updates tab in Setting, i learned that there are no options chosen. Only Other software with some specific DELL sources were available.

To update it I changed the settings and allowed all (main, restricted, universe and multiverse) sources. The system is updated now to 16.04 LTS, and it solved the issue, but it definitely works inconsistently. The sound disappears completely and 'About this computer' still shows 14.04 LTS version.

It seems to be logical to rely on the vendor sources instead of trying to update the system on my own, but there are no guarantees to be up-to-date with security and any other issues... What should I do?

Comment: The obvious question: what did Dell say? If you bought the computer from a physical Dell store have you visited them? Uncertainty over Dell's policy on updates or installing other desktop environments (and now the future of Unity) will make Dell less attractive.

Comment: @DKBose, I bought it with the local reseller. The DELL support is not available on holidays (we have 4 days off in Russia now) and I can't make a support ticket through the DELL site, since it asks to use the analyze tool beforehand, that is distributed only in the .exe file...

Comment: What you should do is based on what you intend to achieve. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, I want to have working OS, not necessarily the most recent one.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.