# How to get 'Other Software' updates?

Tags: 14.04, update-manager, software-sources

As a follow-up to my [first question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912611/should-i-update-certified-ubuntu), I'm curious about proper updating strategy for certified Ubuntu machines.

I have a laptop with pre-installed Ubuntu. To solve some weird issue, I tried to update the system and it led me to broken drivers and an inconsistently working system.

I recovered the system and have the factory image 14.04 LTS and everything looks fine. However, being completely new to Ubuntu, I'm afraid that any update can break my system again. Currently all 'Downloadable from Internet' repositories in **Software & Updates** settings are turned off. However there are a number of repositories added by default:

[image]

I think it's no coincidence that these repositories are added and all the Ubuntu repositories disabled by default. So, to keep the system in a consistent state, and avoid the mistakes I made before, I don't want to allow Ubuntu repositories at all. In the meanwhile, I have no idea how to get updates from the 'Other Software' repositories only, or how to tell which programs are brought through these repositories.

How can I keep the software allowed by these repositories up-to-date and prevent other updates at the same time?

Comment: Since most other Dells running Ubuntu worldwide did not break, an upgrade from the Canonical/Dell repositories seems unlikely to be the cause of your original problem. You are chasing the wrong fish.

Comment: @user535733, I can't even imagine what else could cause such problems. I literally did not anything with the laptop but updating it to LTS 16.04. I didn't install anything, just turned on the Ubuntu repositories, run the command `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and wait till it finishes. After that the laptop rebooted and sound dissapeared. I also was not able to turn on some 'Additional Drivers' from the **Software & Updates** settings..

Comment: @user535733, 16.04 LTS doesn't seem to be compatible since my laptop settings still showed me 14.04 LTS

Comment: `dist-upgrade` will NOT migrate your system from 14.04 to 16.04. Enabling different sources before performing `dist-upgrade` is unwise, and seems likely to cause unexpected behavior. Suggestion: Backup your data, clean-install 16.04, and release-upgrade the proper way next time.

Comment: @user535733, not sure that clearly understand what you mean by clean install. Could elaborate on that please?